# Render a scene with reflections on a completely transparent background

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency

I am trying to render a scene with reflections on a completely transparent background, but the rendered results are not transparent.

The setup:

- White Pills on a reflective surface.
- The reflective surface is supposed to be transparent, like glass with slight roughness on it.
- The environment is set to 0.0, I tried a white environment and a black environment.
- Rendered in Cycles.

The result:

- The rendered PNG has a slight gray to it. Not completely transparent.[image]

The wanted result:

- The pill with its reflection on a completely transparent background.

What was tried:

- Different shading techniques (based on discussions in the interwebs + YT)
- Exporting EXR for use in Photoshop
- Setting the *SCENE - FILM* and ticking the *TRANSPARENT* tick box doesn't give any favorable result - it removed the reflective surface completely.

New to blender and 3D in general.